# Prim's Algorithm - Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, c++14

I have implemented Prim's Algorithm from Introduction to Algorithms. I have observed that the code is similar to Dijkstra's Algorithm, so I have used my [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://github.com/programmercave0/Algo-Data-Structure/blob/master/Dijkstra%20Algorithm/C%2B%2B/dijkstra.cpp) implementation.

Please review this code and suggest improvements.

To compile on Linux: `g++ -std=c++14 prims.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <queue>

class Graph
{

    struct Vertex
    {
        std::size_t id;
        int distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        Vertex * parent = nullptr;

        Vertex(std::size_t id) : id(id) {}
    };

    using pair_ = std::pair<std::size_t, int>;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {};

    //adjacency list , store src, dest, and weight
    std::vector< std::vector< pair_> > adj_list;
    //to store unprocessed vertex min-priority queue
    std::priority_queue< pair_, std::vector<pair_>,
                         std::greater<pair_> > unprocessed;

  public:
    Graph(std::size_t size);
    void add_edge(std::size_t src, std::size_t dest, int weight);
    void prim(std::size_t vertex);
    std::size_t  minimum_cost() ;
};

Graph::Graph(std::size_t size)
{
    vertices.reserve(size);
    adj_list.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        vertices.emplace_back(i);
    }
}

void Graph::add_edge(std::size_t src , std::size_t dest, int weight)
{
    if(weight >= 0)
    {
        if (src == dest)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Source and destination vertices are same");
        }

        if (src < 0 || vertices.size() <= src)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Enter correct source vertex");
        }

        if (dest < 0 || vertices.size() <= dest)
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Enter correct destination vertex");
        }

        int flag = 0, i = src;
        for (auto& it : adj_list[i])
        {
            if (it.first == dest)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            adj_list[src].push_back( {dest, weight} );
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Existing edge");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Negative weight\n";
    }
}

void Graph::prim(std::size_t vertex)
{
    vertices[vertex].distance = 0;
    vertices[vertex].parent = &vertices[vertex];

    unprocessed.push( std::make_pair(vertices[vertex].distance, vertex) );
     while (!unprocessed.empty())
     {
         int curr_vertex_dist = unprocessed.top().first;
         std::size_t curr_vertex = unprocessed.top().second;
         unprocessed.pop();

        for (auto& ver: adj_list[curr_vertex])
        {
            auto& next_dist = vertices[ver.first].distance;
            const auto curr_dist = ver.second;
            if (curr_dist < next_dist)
            {
                next_dist = curr_dist;
                //make src vertex parent of dest vertex
                vertices[ver.first].parent = &vertices[curr_vertex];
                unprocessed.push( std::make_pair(next_dist, ver.first));    
            }
        }
    }
}

std::size_t  Graph::minimum_cost() 
{
    std::size_t cost = 0;
    for (auto vertex: vertices)
    {
        cost = cost + vertex.distance;
    }
    return cost;
}

int main()
{
    Graph grp(9);
    grp.add_edge(0, 1, 4);
    grp.add_edge(0, 2, 8);
    grp.add_edge(1, 2, 11);
    grp.add_edge(1, 3, 8);
    grp.add_edge(3, 4, 2);
    grp.add_edge(4, 2, 7);
    grp.add_edge(2, 5, 1);
    grp.add_edge(5, 4, 6);
    grp.add_edge(3, 6, 7);
    grp.add_edge(3, 8, 4);
    grp.add_edge(5, 8, 2);
    grp.add_edge(6, 7, 9);
    grp.add_edge(6, 8, 14);
    grp.add_edge(7, 8, 10);
    grp.prim(0);
    std::cout << "The total cost is : " << grp.minimum_cost() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Keeping references to potentially dangling pointers

I can see a potential problem with the line

```
vertices[ver.first].parent = &vertices[curr_vertex];
```

if the `std::vector<Vertex> vertices` would be reorganised due to changes in length.
The address you take there isn't stable.

Maybe a better solution would be to keep a

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vertex>> vertices;
```

instead of keeping copies of the `Vertex` instances.

Then you can change

```
vertices[ver.first].parent = &vertices[curr_vertex];
```

to

```
vertices[ver.first].parent = vertices[curr_vertex].get();
```

Since all the vertices are in private scope of the `Graph` class the `std::unique_ptr<Vertex>` instances stored to the `vertices` vector will never invalidate, as long you guarantee to remove all child `Vertex` instances when a parent `Vertex` instane is removed from the graph (Well, that's not an operation in question here, but needs to be considered for production code).

#### 2. Inconsistent error handling

Here

```
else
{
    std::cerr << "Negative weight\n";
}
```

you just use kind of errorneous input being reported to the console, while you throw exceptions for other cases.

For this condition you should rather do

- throwing an exception
- applying an `assert()` call in 1st place
- **clarify from the function signature**

  If *Negative weight* is erroneous input you should make that clear in 1st place:

  ```
    void Graph::add_edge(std::size_t src , std::size_t dest, unsigned weight)
                                                          // ^^^^^^^^
  ```

  This way violations would be covered by the compiler, before runtime detects that flaw.

#### 3. Storing unnecessary information

In your code example `parent` is never used besides storing the information. I am aware that you might have been simplified the actual usage of `parent` with this review question, but with the code context you give, that member variable doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I do not understand. Here we are making a node/vertex as a parent to other node/vertex.

Comment: @coder As mentioned, the address you take there isn't stable. It points to an element address in that `std::vector`. As soon this `std::vector` will be resized, that address is invalidated.

Comment: @coder I realized that using `std::reference_wrapper` won't work either. `std::unique_ptr` seems to be the right tool to express ownership here.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not the right tool. The right tool is `std::size_t`. The problem with the invalidation of iterators/references can be completely alleviated by storing the index of the member and not a reference to it. The only thing necessary is then to call `operator[]`

Comment: @miscco Feel free to write another answer with some example code.